# Using Webpack defineplugin for logging

Tags: webpack

I've been using Webpack for on a project of mine for a while now and it's been great, till this morning when I updated my devdeps. It's still great, but I have a mystery error:

```
{ SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:5)
at Parser.pp$4.raise (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2431:15)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:616:10)
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1963:12)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (\node_modules\acorn-dynamic-import\lib\inject.js:55:31)
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1831:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1808:19)
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1750:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1733:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1710:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2008:32) pos: 5, loc: Position { line: 1, column: 5 }, raisedAt: 5 }
```

I love it when none of my code is in the call stack! :)

A couple points about this before moving on.

1. The error only occurs on production builds and unit tests. It does NOT occur in the dev builds
2. The error doesn't result in any failures. The builds complete. All tests run and pass normally. There are no obvious adverse impacts on the production builds.

It took me a few minutes of experimentation to track down the offending lines. Turns out it was the Webpack Defineplugin, or rather, how I'm using it. I've been conditionally injecting debug logs into my code without a wrapping conditional:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    DEBUG_LOG:  DEBUG ? 'console.log' : '// ',
    DEBUG_WARN: DEBUG ? 'console.warn' : '// ',
    DEBUG_ERR:  DEBUG ? 'console.error' : '// '
}),
```

Usage is simple enough:

```
DEBUG_LOG('something useful');
DEBUG_WARN('something unusual');
DEBUG_ERR('fire bad! fire bad!');
```

When it runs in dev I get useful debug messages and in prod those messages are converted to comments and stripped out by the minifier.

It looks like Webpack is using AcornJS and it's not happy with what I've done here and I can't quite figure out why. Before running the plugin they just evaluate to undefined functions. In dev, they evaluate to `console.log`s, and Acorn seems fine with *that*. In prod/test, they evaluate to comments, which again, are fine (so long as they're single-line comments, and they are). On the one hand everything seems to be working, but errors make me wary and I'd like to understand why it's complaining before re-releasing this to the wild. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In your debug version webpack does the following:

```
DEBUG_LOG('test ' + myvar);
```

becomes

```
(console.log)('test ' + myvar);
```

So it's a IIFE (immediately invoked function execution) and not only a string replacement as one would think.
This means that the comment does not work, because it would create something like this:

```
(//)('test ' + myvar);
```

which has obviously wrong a wrong syntax and this is where things fail.

I think your solution is fragile and would suggest using [strip-loader](https://github.com/yahoo/strip-loader) instead.

Comment: Your analysis doesn't match what I observe in my output (there are no wrapping parentheses)... Is there an intermediate step before it gets written to disk? Regarding fragility, yea... The defineplugin is inspired by `#define`s in traditional compilers where solutions like this are more common, but the plugin would need to have macro-like support to enable this to be more robust. I'll play with Strip Loader and if it works out accept this answer.